# auto enter password for `passwd <new user>` from script?

Tags: scripting, passwd

if the script was `useradd ...............<new_user>; passwd <new_user>;`. is there a way to put the new password in a script? I don't need to change or add an old password for an existing user. I need to enter a brand new password twice when prompted.

Comment: See [How to automatically add user account AND password with a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328528/10931455)

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the previous questions, but I didn't see that one.

Comment: I'm not changing a password, I'm setting it for the first time. I found the answer in the previous link.

Comment: @dbruceh Changing the password or setting the password is the same thing if you're root.

Answer (score 1):

`openssl rand -base64 8 | passwd --stdin <new user>`